# Why has Java Web Start cached this unrelated bit of HTML?

Tags: java, caching, java-web-start

I'm developing a new java web start capability for an existing site.  All is going well except that *one* of my test launches, on *one* of machines has become mysteriously contaminated in a way that is so strange, I'm grasping at straws to explain.

Before the details, some general facts.   The script works everywhere else.  It fails from this one machine, only when logged in as one particular user.  It fails if launched directly from the web, or if the local .jnlp file is launched directly from javaws.

The symptom when it fails is javaws reports "error at line 145", which is itself inexplicable since the jnlp file has only about 15 lines.  The smoking gun is that if I use javaws -verbose, I see the following text as the text of the file that failed to parse.

```
<!--
# Copyright (C) 2009, CyberTAN Corporation
# All Rights Reserved.
# 
# THIS SOFTWARE IS OFFERED "AS IS", AND CYBERTAN GRANTS NO WARRANTIES OF ANY
...
```

plus some suspicious looking javascript.  I've determined that this text is what
my router presents when someone connected to the guest wireless network tries to 
access the web for the first time.

So my working theory is that once during the testing phase, I booted up my netbook,
accidentally was connected to the guest network instead of the regular network,
managed to access the web jnlp file as the first network access, and got this
page in response instead of the expected.

My question is, where (and why) is this text persisting in the system?  I've I ran a search
everywhere, including hidden files, and can't find this text residing anywhere.  I've also
flushed javaws caches using the -viewer option.

Comment: Has "this one machine" been compromised?

Comment: there's no evidence of that.  The suspect HTML comes from my own router.  The mysteries are "where is it cached" and "why is the cached copy still being used" for this one url.

Comment: When you "flushed javaws caches," did you also delete the applications, applets, trace and log files?

Comment: I used the -viewer menu to delete everything that it offered to let me delete.

Comment: You might examine (or delete) the contents of the cache directory or redirect the cache to an empty directory.

Comment: "The cache directory" is a loosely defined variable.  Windows and windoze apps cache stuff all over the place.

Comment: Yes, and the interface varies considerably; I meant to refer to the one you can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still see the App in the Java Cache Viewer GUI (javaws -viewer)?

Try to delete the cache at **C:\Documents and Settings\[account]\Local Settings\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache** (or similar, assuming you're using Windows)...

Here's some additional info: http://www.ngs.ac.uk/clearwebstartcache

Have you updated the URL to your JNLP? Here's some discussion going in this direction: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9804718

Personally, I wouldn't bother too much about the how and why - WebStart can be weird at times. Just ix the problem on your "one machine" and try to keep your productive JNLP as stable as possible.

Comment: Meantime, the "stuck" machine has become unstuck, and while I can reproduce the original problem at will, I can't reproduce the stuck state.   When something like this happens to me, it's an opportunity to dig into the entrails and maybe learn something.  When it happens to one of my clients, it's a nightmare.  It's never very satisfactory to solve a problem by saying "hope it goes away"

Comment: I agree. I think the main problem is that WebStart doesn't really get too much (or any at all?) attention from Oracle anymore. Recently, I migrated an App from using plain JNLP download to the JnlpDownloadServlet (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) as it enables some features that should be standard in WebStart. And where do I get the Servlet from? I need to copy the source file from the JDK samples... :-/ Makes me think: Are you using the Servlet? Might even help on your caching problem (maybe...)...